# React native does not return children prop

Tags: reactjs, react-native, children

I need to return children prop but nothing appears on my screen.
Got two errors back -

```
'Header' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its return type 'void' is not a valid JSX element.
```

Second error -

```
Type '{ iconLeft: string; label: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & HeaderItemProps'.
  Property 'iconLeft' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & HeaderItemProps'.
```

**Main component**

```
type HeaderProps = {
    children: React.ReactNode;
};

type HeaderItemProps = {
    label: string;
    iconLeft?: IconName<32>;
};

export function Header({ children }: HeaderProps) {
    <View>{children}</View>;
}

export function HeaderItem({ label, iconLeft,}: HeaderItemProps) {
    return (
        <Pressable onPress={onPress} style={styles.container}>
            {iconLeft && <Icon size={32} name={iconLeft} />}
            <Text>{label}</Text>
        </Pressable>
    );
}
```

**File where i have the children**

```
export function Children()

return (
    <View>
            <Header iconLeft="icon2" label="item" /> 
    </View>
);
}
```

**Tried also returning like this**

```
<Header>
 <HeaderItem iconLeft="icon2" label="item" />
</Header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Header component should return that jsx data, you have missing return statement.

```
export function Header({ children }: HeaderProps) {
    return (<View>{children}</View>);
}
```